# Convert named matches in MatchData to Hash

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I have a rather simple regexp, but I wanted to use named regular expressions to make it cleaner and then iterate over results.

Testing string:

```
testing_string = "111x222b333"
```

My regexp:

```
regexp = %r{
                (?<width> [0-9]{3} ) {0}
                (?<height> [0-9]{3} ) {0}
                (?<depth> [0-9]+ ) {0}

                \g<width>x\g<height>b\g<depth>
            }x
dimensions = regexp.match(testing_string)
```

This work like a charm, but heres where the problem comes:

```
dimensions.each { |k, v| dimensions[k] = my_operation(v) }

# ERROR !

 undefined method `each' for #<MatchData "111x222b333" width:"111" height:"222" depth:"333">.
```

There is no .`each` method in MatchData object, and I really don't want to monkey patch it.

How can I fix this problem ?

I wasn't as clear as I thought: **the point is to keep names** and hash-like structure.

Comment: Please, be more clear next time. Otherwise answerers like me will be downvoted after clarification :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you need a full Hash:

```
captures = Hash[ dimensions.names.zip( dimensions.captures ) ]
p captures
#=> {"width"=>"111", "height"=>"222", "depth"=>"333"}
```

If you just want to iterate over the name/value pairs:

```
dimensions.names.each do |name|
  value = dimensions[name]
  puts "%6s -> %s" % [ name, value ]
end
#=>  width -> 111
#=> height -> 222
#=>  depth -> 333
```

Alternatives:

```
dimensions.names.zip( dimensions.captures ).each do |name,value|
  # ...
end

[ dimensions.names, dimensions.captures ].transpose.each do |name,value|
  # ...
end

dimensions.names.each.with_index do |name,i|
  value = dimensions.captures[i]
  # ...
end
```

Comment: The versions using dimensions.captures don't work if the same name is used multiple times. Using `dimensions[name]` returns the last successful match, like Ruby 2.4's named_captures.

I use the following to emulate named_captures: `matchdata.names.map { |n| [n, matchdata[n]] }.to_h`

Answer (score 11):

So today a new Ruby version (2.4.0) [was released](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/) which [includes many new features](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0/NEWS), amongst them [feature #11999](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11999), aka `MatchData#named_captures`. This means you can now do this:

```
h = '12'.match(/(?<a>.)(?<b>.)(?<c>.)?/).named_captures
#=> {"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>nil}
h.class
#=> Hash
```

So in your code change

```
dimensions = regexp.match(testing_string)
```

to

```
dimensions = regexp.match(testing_string).named_captures
```

And you can use the `each` method on your regex match result just like on any other `Hash`, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd attack the whole problem of creating the hash a bit differently:

```
irb(main):052:0> testing_string = "111x222b333"
"111x222b333"
irb(main):053:0> hash = Hash[%w[width height depth].zip(testing_string.scan(/\d+/))]
{
    "width" => "111",
    "height" => "222",
    "depth" => "333"
}
```

While regex are powerful, their siren-call can be too alluring, and we get sucked into trying to use them when there are more simple, or straightforward, ways of accomplishing something. It's just something to think about.

---

To keep track of the number of elements scanned, per the OPs comment:

```
hash = Hash[%w[width height depth].zip(scan_result = testing_string.scan(/\d+/))]
=> {"width"=>"111", "height"=>"222", "depth"=>"333"}
scan_result.size
=> 3
```

Also `hash.size` will return that, as would the size of the array containing the keys, etc.

Comment: I'm just a simple guy and maintaining regex is not my idea of fun. :-)

Comment: It's very good suggestion, not only in this case but also in whole programming KISS. I try to obey to the simplicity rule every time, but unfortunatelly in this case I need to keep track of how many numbers i get each time.

Comment: You can tell how many numbers you get very easily, by assigning the result of the scan to a variable, getting its size, then passing that into the hash. But, that requirement wasn't stated in your question.

Answer (score 1):

[@Phrogz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690565/1886865) is correct if all of your captures have unique names, but you're allowed to give multiple captures the same name. [Here's an example from the Regexp documentation.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures)

This code supports captures with duplicate names:

```
captures = Hash[
  dimensions.regexp.named_captures.map do |name, indexes|
    [
      name,
      indexes.map { |i| dimensions.captures[i - 1] }
    ]
  end
]

# Iterate over the captures
captures.each do |name, values|
  # name is a String
  # values is an Array of Strings
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From Ruby [3.3.0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/6952) `symbolize_names: true` option is available for [`MatchData#named_captures`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/MatchData.html#method-i-named_captures)

If keyword argument `symbolize_names` is given a true value, the keys in the resulting hash are Symbols

```rb
m = "12".match(/(?<a>.)(?<b>.)(?<c>.)?/) #=> #<MatchData "12" a:"1" b:"2" c:nil>

m.named_captures #=> {"a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c" => nil}
m.named_captures(symbolize_names: true) #=> {:a => "1", :b => "2", :c => nil}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the names, you can do

```
new_dimensions = {}
dimensions.names.each { |k| new_dimensions[k] = my_operation(dimensions[k]) }
```

Comment: That's exacly what i want, to keep my names. Your code won't work anyway, because there is no []= method for MatchData.

Comment: I copied that from your code, because I didn't know what you wanted to do with the hash.  I modified my code to put the results in a new hash.  But doing `dimensions.names.zip(dimensions.captures)` as suggested by Phrogz is even cleaner.