# make hash consistent when some of its keys are symbols and others are not

Tags: regex, ruby, hash

I use this code to merge a Matchdata with a Hash :

```
  params = {
    :url => 'http://myradiowebsite.com/thestation'
  }

  pattern = Regexp.new('^https?://(?:www.)?myradiowebsite.com/(?<station_slug>[^/]+)/?$')
  matchdatas = pattern.match(params[:url])
  #convert named matches in MatchData to Hash
  #https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690565/782013
  datas = Hash[ matchdatas.names.zip( matchdatas.captures ) ]

  params = params.merge(datas)
```

But this gives me mixed keys in my *params* hash:

> {:url=>"http://myradiowebsite.com/thestation", "station_slug"=>"thestation"}

Which is a problem to get the hash values using the keys later.  I would like to standardize them to symbols.

I'm learning Ruby, can someone explain me if there is something wrong with this code, and how to improve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can skip converting and inject the key you need `params[:station_slug] = matchdatas[:station_slug]`. And why do you even need this? You can try `URI.parse` to decompose URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transform the keys of `datas` to symbols:

```
Hash[ matchdatas.names.zip( matchdatas.captures ) ].transform_keys(&:to_sym)
```

Or to define your params hash with string keys:

```
params = { 'url' => 'http://myradiowebsite.com/thestation' }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, note that with

```
pattern = 
  Regexp.new('^https?://(?:www.)?myradiowebsite.com/(?<station_slug>[^/]+)/?$')
  #=> /^https?:\/\/(?:www.)?myradiowebsite.com\/(?<station_slug>[^\/]+)\/?$/
```

we obtain

```
'http://wwwXmyradiowebsiteYcom/thestation'.match?(pattern)
   #=> true
```

which means that the periods after `'www'` and before `'com'` need to be escaped:

```
pattern =
  Regexp.new('\Ahttps?://(?:www\.)?myradiowebsite\.com/(?<station_slug>[^/]+)/?\z')
  #=> /\Ahttps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?myradiowebsite\.com\/(?<station_slug>[^\/]+)\/?\z/
```

I've also replaced the beginning-of-line anchor (`^`) with the beginning-of-string anchor (`\A`) and the end-of-line anchor (`$`) with the end-of-string anchor (`\z`), though either can be used here since the string consists of a single line.

You *are given* the two keys you want in the hash you are returning: `:url` and `:station_slug`, so for

```
params = { :url => 'http://myradiowebsite.com/thestation' }
```

you can compute

```
m = params[:url].match(pattern)
  #=> #<MatchData "http://myradiowebsite.com/thestation" station_slug:"thestation">
```

then so long as `m` is not `nil` (as here), write

```
{ :url => m[0], :station_slug => m["station_slug"] }
  #=> {:url=>"http://myradiowebsite.com/thestation", :station_slug=>"thestation"}
```

See [MatchData#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D). `m[0]` returns the entire match; `m["station_slug"]` returns the contents of the capture group named `"station_slug"`.

Obviously, the name of the capture group can be any valid string, or you could make it an unnamed capture group and write

```
{ :url => m[0], :station_slug => m[1] }
```